# How to add markers to current location on Google Maps v2?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am making a location based reminder app and want to know how to add markers to the current location.

I am using the following code:

```
 public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(googleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 10f));

    //Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.

    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            mMap.clear();
            locationLat = latLng.latitude;
            locationLong = latLng.longitude;

            AddLocationActivity.this.addMarker(new LatLng(locationLat,locationLong), AddLocationActivity.locationName);

            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(locationLat,locationLong), 10.9f));
            AddLocationActivity.this.mainClass.locationName = address;
            Log.i("AddLocationActivity",""+AddLocationActivity.this.mainClass.locationName);

        }
    });

}
```

Is there any method to zoom the map view and/or add markers to the current location?

Comment: Have a look at their documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker.

Answer (score 1):

change your code according to following:

```
 mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
        mMap.clear();
        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Title"));
        marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN));

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10.9f));
    }
});
```

Comment: Replace your code portion for setOnMapClickListener() below the cooment line with these code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
LatLng markerLocation = new LatLng(latitude,longitude); // latitude and longitude must be a float or double
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(markerLocation)); // any title you want
```

for zooming the map view, there is a default function already. use hand gestures if you want to add a bottom, you can add zoom controls

Here is the whole code

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(googleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 10f));

    //Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.

    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            mMap.clear();

            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10f));
            Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)); 

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i dnt get you,,,please tell me which line i should replace for this code,,,

Answer (score 1):

Try this way this worked for me

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
 GoogleMap map;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

  lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

  map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
    .getMap();

 }

 @Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

  map.clear();

  MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();

  mp.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

  mp.title("my position");

  map.addMarker(mp);

  map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
    new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 16));

 }

 @Override
 public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override
 public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override
 public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

}
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You first need to get the current location by a onlicationchangelistener in google maps. here is the listener in the code.

Then place marker according to that location you got.

*Below is the code part-*

```
private GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
    LatLng loc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    if(mMarker == null){
       mMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc));
    }else{
       mMarker.remove();
       mMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc));
    }
       mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 16.0f));
 }
};
```

add the listener to maps.

```
mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener);
```

This will put marker in the current lcoation.

Comment: it is deprecated method